# How to evaluate K-Means Clustering since automatic indexes of clusters don't match true labels?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, multilabel-classification

How do we measure the accuracy of a K-Means clustering algorithm (say, generate a confusion matrix) since the automatic indexes of cluster is probably a permutation of the original labels?

Comment: Can you please add example code?

Comment: There is a specially dedicated [homogeneity_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html) from sklearn for the cases like this

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov oh this is the perfect answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you mean too. Your original labels perhaps is the ground truth labeling. The clustering results provided by k-means is usually an integer with range given as many as the k clusters you wish the k-means algorithm to give you.

I typically use `pandas.crosstab` function to visualize the localizations of the groundtruth labeling with kmeans labeling with cross-tabulation.

For better visualization, you may want to use the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))

# plot the heatmap for correlation matrix
ax = sns.heatmap(crosstab_groundtruth_kmeans.T, 
                square=True, annot=True, fmt='.2f')

ax.set_yticklabels(
    ax.get_yticklabels(),
    rotation=0);
```

`out:`
[image]

Good luck!~

Answer (score 1):

k-means is a clustering (grouping algorithm, not used for classification), hence, it is not feasible to check and analyze accuracy. Major concept of k-means is to find a cluster of data-points which maximize the "between-cluster" distance (and does not have the concept of labels, and hence, you can't get accuracy matrix). More insights: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means

The accuracy (assuming, you want to visualize which cluster consists of which data points) has to be analyzed manually using the `predict` method from `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`. It basically "Predicts the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to." ([from documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html))